# About boost-python: dyld: Symbol not found: _PyBaseObject_Type

Tags: python, c++, boost, ld, boost-python

When I run my code, I meet a problem about boost-python. Just like this:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _PyBaseObject_Type
Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
Expected in: flat namespace
```

My project could run correctly several months ago. But now, when I reconfigure the environment, it can not run.

-Severals months ago, I used homebrew to configure the environment, just like this:

```
brew install boost
brew install python
brew install boost-python
brew install opencv(My project is an Opencv project)
```

-But now, it doesn't work and the error is just like above. So I use Macports to install boost, like this:

```
sudo port install boost
sudo port install py27-pip
sudo port select --set python python27
sudo port select --set pip pip27
sudo port install py27-numpy
brew install opencv(The version of opencv in port is 3.0, so i use brew)
```

-But it has the same problem.

Who knows how to deal with this problem? Is it about the boost-python? How should I to install boost-python correctly? Is it about the version of boost/boost-python?

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem? I am facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention your boost version and/or your compiler. But I found [a very similar issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue21122) on the Python's bug tracker.

As you seem to use the `ld` linker, you should try to link your code with `-Wl,--export_dynamic`.